# Marketing Cloud Business Unit Copy

Tags: marketing-cloud, duplicate-management, migration

I have a Parent and Child Business Unit hierarchy and I want to duplicate a "template" child BU numerous times. It is setup with data extensions, imports, extracts, queries and all the things I need for all the BUs to include.

Is there a way to copy the template BU's complete structure to a new BU? I do not want to copy over any records although if I had to and delete them that would be fine.
I have heard about the App DEG Reactor and a custom SOAP/.Net method but if there are any other known methods that would be good, including possible Salesforce tech support?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is either to contact DEG or use the marketing cloud APIs to do this. Support Could do this but it would be a **VERY** expensive professional service arrangement.

If you do want to do it yourself....

[Marketing Cloud APIs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm)

Is a good start.